# SQL query to remove SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

My server was hacked like many others yesterday by this one SQL injection attack. I have two tables that have the alien script put in.

My options are:
-Manually delete the script from thousands of database entries.
-Find copies of the tables and replace them.

How I would like to have a SQL query that finds the script beginning with the `**"></title>\****<script**` and ending with `**</script><!--**` and removing it from all the database entries that have it.

Example:
So the query would see a databse entry like `"></title><script> </script><!--Aland Islands 
and remove "></title><script> </script><!--`
leaving just `Aland Islands` behind.

P.S. I post the full script I want to remove just in case. Sorry for some reason stackoverflow isnt letting post some of this info.

Comment: i think that allowing an injection to reach that far as the db itself, is not the right way to go. you should stop the injection/malicous scripts at the application itself ( the site ).

Comment: Yeah I dont know where its coming from right now. Odd cause the two tables that are effected there are no scripts that update them form the website.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take the DB offline, export the tables into load scripts, then use a text editor or `sed` to remove the malicious text, then truncate the tables and load them back in using the load scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I do actually have copies of the tables. Just wanted to take an easier road.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
DELETE FROM infected_table
FROM
    infected_table i
WHERE
    i.script_column LIKE '>%'
```

Please do try the LIKE clause using a SELECT before running it though or run it in a transaction checking that the result is correct before committing.

Answer (score 0):

1st find all the vulnerable Links on your site then change the version of mysql you are using because the error which help to attacker to find your site is vulnerable or not is due to the error. If your web application on php there are several other error which help to attacker to find site is vulnerable or not. You can use acunetix web vulnerability scanner for find all venerability on web application.